# Missing EDMX file from inherited VB.Net Entity Framework 6.1 project

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

First of all I'm new to Entity Framework and have inherited a vb.net project.  I'm trying to add an existing table to the model.  The table is in the same database the model refers to.

I've read and watched lots and theoretically understand what I need to do but everyone speaks about right clicking on the emdx file and click on 'Update Model from Database'.  This project doesn't have an emdx file.  (hidden or otherwise)

So I'm confused.  So I have one?

If not can anyone advise me on another way to update the model to add an already existing table please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've read and watched lots and theoretically understand what I need to do but everyone speaks about right clicking on the emdx file and click on 'Update Model from Database'

That's just one approach to EF: "database first" where the database is designed and then the EF Model (in the form of a `.edmx` file) is part of the project (and then used to generate the code files for db context and entity types).

The other two approaches are "Model First" where the designer (or direct XML editing) is used to write the `.edmx` directly.

Finally – and this is what you might have – there is "Code First" where the `DbContext` derived type and entity types are written directly. Check the `DbContext` derived type and the entity types being hand written (or at least maintained).

For information on the different approaches the EF's [documentation site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ee712907) includes introductory articles including a [video about the different models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj590134).